# SQL Server: Recursive query is not optimised with global WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, recursion, query-optimization

I have a recursive SQL query, which I would like to put into a view. I obtain the correct result, but this query take time (about 20 seconds)
The execution plan shows that the filtering (WHERE clause) is applied in the end. If I put the WHERE clause in CTE, it takes less than 1 second.

Do you know if it's possible to optimize the query so that the CTE part would not parse the entire table?

```
WITH CrfTransaction AS (
    SELECT ID_CRF, 1 Transaction_Number
    FROM TCRF_Detail
    WHERE Prev_Id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT crfd1.ID_CRF, crfd2.Transaction_Number + 1
    FROM TCRF_Detail crfd1
        JOIN CrfTransaction crfd2 ON crfd2.ID_CRF = crfd1.Prev_Id       
)
SELECT (columns ...)
FROM CrfTransaction crft
    JOIN TCRF_Detail crfd ON crft.ID_CRF = crfd.ID_CRF
    (JOIN ...)
WHERE crfd.Asset = 366 AND crfd.Slot = '1' AND crfd.Port = '11'
ORDER BY crfd.Asset, crfd.Slot, crfd.Port, crfd.Connector, crft.Transaction_Number
```

Comment: Why don't you put the WHERE clause in the CTE?

Comment: Because I want to create a view. The CTE will be a part of the view and the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses will be in the SELECT FROM my_view.